# A complex SQL Query using count, sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql queries and I am stuck on the following question. I have tried to write some nested query using count but it is always giving error.

List the last name, the first name, and the number of projects for the manager whose department controls the maximum number of projects.

Following is the database given

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `company` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `company`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `department`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `department` (
  `Dname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Dnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mgr_ssn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Mgr_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `department` (`Dname`, `Dnumber`, `Mgr_ssn`, `Mgr_start_date`) VALUES
('Headquarters', 1, '888665555', '1981-06-19'),
('Administration', 4, '987654321', '1995-01-01'),
('Research', 5, '333445555', '1988-05-22'),
('Software', 6, '111111100', '2009-05-15'),
('Hardware', 7, '444444400', '2008-05-15'),
('Sales', 8, '555555500', '2007-01-01');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dependent`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dependent` (
  `Essn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Dependent_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relationship` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `dependent` (`Essn`, `Dependent_name`, `Sex`, `Bdate`, `Relationship`) VALUES
('121231234', 'abcd', 'M', '2001-05-22', 'Son'),
('123456789', 'Alice', 'F', '1988-12-30', 'Daughter'),
('123456789', 'Elizabeth', 'F', '1967-05-05', 'Spouse'),
('123456789', 'Michael', 'M', '1988-01-04', 'Son'),
('333445555', 'Alice', 'F', '1986-04-05', 'Daughter'),
('333445555', 'Joy', 'F', '1958-05-03', 'Spouse'),
('333445555', 'Theodore', 'M', '1983-10-25', 'Son'),
('444444400', 'Johnny', 'M', '2007-04-04', 'Son'),
('444444400', 'Tommy', 'M', '2009-06-07', 'Son'),
('444444401', 'Chris', 'M', '1979-04-19', 'Spouse'),
('444444402', 'Alec', 'M', '1974-02-14', 'Spouse'),
('987654321', 'Abner', 'M', '1942-02-28', 'Spouse');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dept_locations`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dept_locations` (
  `Dnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Dlocation` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `dept_locations` (`Dnumber`, `Dlocation`) VALUES
(1, 'Houston'),
(4, 'Stafford'),
(5, 'Bellaire'),
(5, 'Houston'),
(5, 'Sugarland'),
(6, 'Atlanta'),
(6, 'Sacramento'),
(7, 'Milwaukee'),
(8, 'Chicago'),
(8, 'Dallas'),
(8, 'Miami'),
(8, 'Philadephia'),
(8, 'Seattle');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `Fname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Minit` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Ssn` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `Bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Super_ssn` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dno` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `employee` (`Fname`, `Minit`, `Lname`, `Ssn`, `Bdate`, `Address`, `Sex`, `Salary`, `Super_ssn`, `Dno`) VALUES
('Jared', 'D', 'James', '111111100', '1976-10-10', '123 Peachtree, Atlanta, GA', 'M', 85000.00, NULL, 6),
('Jon', 'C', 'Jones', '111111101', '1977-11-14', '111 Allgood, Atlanta, GA', 'M', 45000.00, '111111100', 6),
('Justin', '', 'Mark', '111111102', '1976-01-12', '2342 May, Atlanta, GA', 'M', 40000.00, '111111100', 6),
('Brad', 'C', 'Knight', '111111103', '1978-02-13', '176 Main St., Atlanta, GA', 'M', 44000.00, '111111100', 6),
('John', 'B', 'Smith', '123456789', '1965-01-09', '731 Fondren, Houston, TX', 'M', 30000.00, '333445555', 5),
('Evan', 'E', 'Wallis', '222222200', '1968-01-16', '134 Pelham, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 92000.00, NULL, 7),
('Josh', 'U', 'Zell', '222222201', '1964-05-22', '266 McGrady, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 56000.00, '222222200', 7),
('Andy', 'C', 'Vile', '222222202', '1954-06-21', '1967 Jordan, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 53000.00, '222222200', 7),
('Tom', 'G', 'Brand', '222222203', '1976-12-16', '112 Third St, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 62500.00, '222222200', 7),
('Jenny', 'F', 'Vos', '222222204', '1977-11-11', '263 Mayberry, Milwaukee, WI', 'F', 61000.00, '222222201', 7),
('Chris', 'A', 'Carter', '222222205', '1970-03-21', '565 Jordan, Milwaukee, WI', 'F', 43000.00, '222222201', 7),
('Kim', 'C', 'Grace', '333333300', '1980-10-23', '6677 Mills Ave, Sacramento, CA', 'F', 79000.00, NULL, 6),
('Jeff', 'H', 'Chase', '333333301', '1980-01-07', '145 Bradbury, Sacramento, CA', 'M', 44000.00, '333333300', 6),
('Franklin', 'T', 'Wong', '333445555', '1955-12-08', '638 Voss, Houston, TX', 'M', 40000.00, '888665555', 5),
('Alex', 'D', 'Freed', '444444400', '1960-10-09', '4333 Pillsbury, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 89000.00, NULL, 7),
('Bonnie', 'S', 'Bays', '444444401', '1966-06-19', '111 Hollow, Milwaukee, WI', 'F', 70000.00, '444444400', 7),
('Alec', 'C', 'Best', '444444402', '1976-06-18', '233 Solid, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 60000.00, '444444400', 7),
('Sam', 'S', 'Snedden', '444444403', '1987-07-31', '987 Windy St, Milwaukee, WI', 'M', 48000.00, '444444400', 7),
('Joyce', 'A', 'English', '453453453', '1972-07-31', '5631 Rice, Houston, TX', 'F', 25000.00, '333445555', 5),
('John', 'C', 'James', '555555500', '1985-06-30', '7676 Bloomington, Sacramento, CA', 'M', 81000.00, NULL, 6),
('Nandita', 'K', 'Ball', '555555501', '1979-04-16', '222 Howard, Sacramento, CA', 'M', 62000.00, '555555500', 6),
('Bob', 'B', 'Bender', '666666600', '1978-04-17', '8794 Garfield, Chicago, IL', 'M', 96000.00, NULL, 8),
('Jill', 'J', 'Jarvis', '666666601', '1976-01-14', '6234 Lincoln, Chicago, IL', 'F', 36000.00, '666666600', 8),
('Kate', 'W', 'King', '666666602', '1976-04-16', '1976 Boone Trace, Chicago, IL', 'F', 44000.00, '666666600', 8),
('Lyle', 'G', 'Leslie', '666666603', '1973-06-09', '417 Hancock Ave, Chicago, IL', 'M', 41000.00, '666666601', 8),
('Billie', 'J', 'King', '666666604', '1970-01-01', '556 Washington, Chicago, IL', 'F', 38000.00, '666666603', 8),
('Jon', 'A', 'Kramer', '666666605', '1974-08-22', '1988 Windy Creek, Seattle, WA', 'M', 41500.00, '666666603', 8),
('Ray', 'H', 'King', '666666606', '1959-08-16', '213 Delk Road, Seattle, WA', 'M', 44500.00, '666666604', 8),
('Gerald', 'D', 'Small', '666666607', '1972-05-19', '122 Ball Street, Dallas, TX', 'M', 29000.00, '666666602', 8),
('Arnold', 'A', 'Head', '666666608', '1977-05-19', '233 Spring St, Dallas, TX', 'M', 33000.00, '666666602', 8),
('Helga', 'C', 'Pataki', '666666609', '1979-03-11', '101 Holyoke St, Dallas, TX', 'F', 32000.00, '666666602', 8),
('Naveen', 'B', 'Drew', '666666610', '1980-05-23', '198 Elm St, Philadelphia, PA', 'M', 34000.00, '666666607', 8),
('Carl', 'E', 'Reedy', '666666611', '1987-06-21', '213 Ball St, Philadelphia, PA', 'M', 32000.00, '666666610', 8),
('Sammy', 'G', 'Hall', '666666612', '1980-01-11', '433 Main Street, Miami, FL', 'M', 37000.00, '666666611', 8),
('Red', 'A', 'Bacher', '666666613', '1990-05-21', '196 Elm Street, Miami, FL', 'M', 33500.00, '666666612', 8),
('Ramesh', 'K', 'Narayan', '666884444', '1962-09-15', '971 Fire Oak, Humble, TX', 'M', 38000.00, '333445555', 5),
('James', 'E', 'Borg', '888665555', '1937-11-10', '450 Stone, Houston, TX', 'M', 55000.00, NULL, 1),
('Jennifer', 'S', 'Wallace', '987654321', '1941-06-20', '291 Berry, Bellaire, TX', 'F', 43000.00, '888665555', 4),
('Ahmad', 'V', 'Jabbar', '987987987', '1969-03-29', '980 Dallas, Houston, TX', 'M', 25000.00, '987654321', 4),
('Alicia', 'J', 'Zelaya', '999887777', '1968-07-19', '3321 Castle, Spring, TX', 'F', 25000.00, '987654321', 4);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `project`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
  `Pname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Pnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Plocation` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dnum` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `project` (`Pname`, `Pnumber`, `Plocation`, `Dnum`) VALUES
('ProductX', 1, 'Bellaire', 5),
('ProductY', 2, 'Sugarland', 5),
('ProductZ', 3, 'Houston', 5),
('Computerization', 10, 'Stafford', 4),
('Reorganization', 20, 'Houston', 1),
('Newbenefits', 30, 'Stafford', 4),
('OperatingSystems', 61, 'Jacksonville', 6),
('DatabaseSystems', 62, 'Birmingham', 6),
('Middleware', 63, 'Jackson', 6),
('InkjetPrinters', 91, 'Phoenix', 7),
('LaserPrinters', 92, 'LasVegas', 7);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `works_on`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `works_on` (
  `Essn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Pno` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Hours` float(3,1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `works_on` (`Essn`, `Pno`, `Hours`) VALUES
('111111100', 61, 40.0),
('111111101', 61, 40.0),
('111111102', 61, 40.0),
('111111103', 61, 40.0),
('123456789', 1, 32.5),
('123456789', 2, 7.5),
('222222200', 62, 40.0),
('222222201', 62, 48.0),
('222222202', 62, 40.0),
('222222203', 62, 40.0),
('222222204', 62, 40.0),
('222222205', 62, 40.0),
('333333300', 63, 40.0),
('333333301', 63, 46.0),
('333445555', 2, 10.0),
('333445555', 3, 10.0),
('333445555', 10, 10.0),
('333445555', 20, 10.0),
('444444400', 91, 40.0),
('444444401', 91, 40.0),
('444444402', 91, 40.0),
('444444403', 91, 40.0),
('453453453', 1, 20.0),
('453453453', 2, 20.0),
('555555500', 92, 40.0),
('555555501', 92, 44.0),
('666666601', 91, 40.0),
('666666603', 91, 40.0),
('666666604', 91, 40.0),
('666666605', 92, 40.0),
('666666606', 91, 40.0),
('666666607', 61, 40.0),
('666666608', 62, 40.0),
('666666609', 63, 40.0),
('666666610', 61, 40.0),
('666666611', 61, 40.0),
('666666612', 61, 40.0),
('666666613', 61, 30.0),
('666666613', 62, 10.0),
('666666613', 63, 10.0),
('666884444', 3, 40.0),
('888665555', 20, 0.0),
('987654321', 20, 15.0),
('987654321', 30, 20.0),
('987987987', 10, 35.0),
('987987987', 30, 5.0),
('999887777', 10, 10.0),
('999887777', 30, 30.0);


ALTER TABLE `department`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Dnumber`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `Dname` (`Dname`);

ALTER TABLE `dependent`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Essn`,`Dependent_name`);

ALTER TABLE `dept_locations`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Dnumber`,`Dlocation`);

ALTER TABLE `employee`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Ssn`);

ALTER TABLE `project`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Pnumber`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `Pname` (`Pname`);

ALTER TABLE `works_on`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Essn`,`Pno`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the department that has the maximum number of projects, you can use aggregation:

```
select p.dnum
from projects p
group by p.dnum
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Note the above only returns one value if there are ties.

I'll let you figure out how to join the department and other tables to get the manager's name.

Comment: Yes I have tried, it returned only the department number which has the maximum number of projects. Please let me know if you figure out joining. Thanks @Gordon